# Keep the connection alive in openfire but show user as offline in xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I am developing an android chat application using openfire smack library.I have created a bound service to listen to messages when the is in background.The connection object is also maintained by service.Service is working fine as listening to background messages,but the problem is user is shown online all the time when the app is in background.Keeping the connection is also necessary so that user can listen to messages but this connection is showing user online all the time.I want to show user offline when app is in background.One thing more i am a beginner in android application as well as in xmpp protocol.If you think my question senseless plz don't vote down it because for a beginner every question has sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that user is offline, you need to send presence as unavailable to server so that it is published to your roster entries. Now you should be shown as offline to other users but your session exists so Openfire will route your messages to you. Now on application coming to foreground, you can send again your presence indicating you are available.

Comment: Thanks but i have tried that too..When my presence is set to offline then messages are not delivered to me..

Comment: Then you can't go with current logic, you will have to disconnect XMPP connection after application goes to background (after X mins). And on Openfire end, push notifications support will be required. But there is no official plugin for that.

Comment: What about GCM and CallBackOnOffline plugin in openfire..Should i use that

Comment: CallBackOnOffline: Uses the provided URL to send from & to params of message. So in this case you can write a service (in php or whatever server side language) which will receive request from this plugin, and there you can forward it to GCM (again your own implementation). For GCM, if you are talking about: https://github.com/meisterfuu/Openfire-GCM then it's also doing same thing (Sending to,from,message to a URL)

Comment: But can you tell me how to use CallBackOnOffline plugin...I know how to implement GCM at server side but how can i use it with CallBackOnOffline plugin...You answer will be highly appreciable..Thansks

Comment: I can compile and provide you CallbackOnOffline.jar file which you will have to drop in "plugins/" directory of Openfire and define two properties in openfire properties from admin by going to system properties menu. Then restart the server and it should work :)

Comment: Thanks, you can mail me @ mohitgaur316(at)gmail(dot)com